# How to get all documents shared with specific user by CSOM

Tags: search, csom

I'd need to get a list of all documents in all document libraries in single site, which are "shared with" a specific person. How can I search for them?
For search I use the standard approach

```
using (ClientContext ctx = GetClientContext())
        {
            KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(ctx);
            keywordQuery.QueryText = criteria.KeywordQueryString;
            SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(ctx);
            ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);


            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

but I'm not able to figure out the proper query.

Thanks